# ts-node-dev hot reaload dose not recognize my import file in index.ts

Tags: typescript, ts-node, ts-node-dev

My server `index.ts` file import `consoleColorFy.ts`

`consoleColorFy.ts`

```
declare global {
    interface Console {
        redBg: TConsoleFn;
    }
}
console["redBg"] = ...
```

Now i can use `console.redBg()`.
**It works well in most time** but when hot-reload some server's file

I got this error.

```
Property 'redBg' does not exist on type 'Console'.
>> console.redBg("error", error);
```

`consoleColorFy.ts`, which is imported first, will always work because all code starts from `index.ts`.

But when `ts-node-dev` run `hot-reloaded` by change of code, it seems to only rework some file. and it dose not recognise my `consoleColorFy.ts` Hum.... any advice?

`"ts-node-dev --respawn --no-notify --rs src/index.ts --env=dev"`

It works well when I restart server
Or  when the refreshed file is `index.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `--files`, it works for me.

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#missing-types